# How to display a kaboom.js game in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, kaboom

I'm trying to use the kaboom.js library for the first time. My goal is to display a text in my div with the id `game-placeholder`.

Here's my body:

```
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <h3>Kaboom Game</h3>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="game-placeholder">
  </div>

  <div class="highscores">
    <h2>High Scores</h2>
    <ul id="highscore-list">
      <!-- High scores will be dynamically added here -->
      <li>No high scores yet.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // Kaboom.js game initialization
  kaboom({
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    clearColor: [0, 0, 0, 1],
    scale: 1,
    debug: true,
    global: true,
  });

  add([
    text("Hello, Kaboom.js!", 24),
    pos(100, 100),
    origin("center"),
  ]);


</script>

</body>
```

But for some reason my div always stays black, and I can't seem to get kaboom to initialize. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix that?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Please include a [mre].

Comment: Have you looked at the browser console? Are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `canvas` option of the kaboom.js initializer.

```js
  kaboom({
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    clearColor: [0, 0, 0, 1],
    scale: 1,
    debug: true,
    global: true,
    canvas: document.querySelector("#game-placeholder"),
  });
```